# C# WebBrowser Generate Image ( only required data without white space ) via HTML Content

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap, webbrowser-control

I tried to generate Image via HTML DIV Content.
I succeeded by using below code `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string _GenerateString = @"VisualStudio<sup>ide test</sup>";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();           

sb.Append(" <style type=\"text/css\"> ");
sb.Append(" #_GenerateHTMLToImage_{ ");
sb.Append("     width:...px; ");
sb.Append("     height:...px; ");
sb.Append(" } ");
sb.Append(" </style> ");
sb.Append(" <div id='_GenerateHTMLToImage_'> ");
sb.Append(_GenerateString);
sb.Append(" </div> ");

//var bmp = MakeScreenshot_original(sb.ToString());
var bmp = MakeScreenshot(sb.ToString());
bmp.Save(@"C:\test_web.jpg");
}

public Bitmap MakeScreenshot(string html)
{
// Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

wb.Navigate("about:blank");
if (wb.Document != null){
    wb.Document.Write(html);
}

wb.DocumentText = html;
wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;            
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { 
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); 
}

wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;

// Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control           
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
wb.Dispose();

return bitmap;
}
```

It generate me below image
[image]

But my problem is it generate image ( my required string + **unwanted white space** ).
I don't know how to generate image only string that I want and removed any white space.

I had changed parameter values from below lines...

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(xxx, xxx);
wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(xxx, xxx, xxxx, xxxx));
```

But, even I had changed parameter integer values , I still not satisfy the outcome.

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default stylesheet gives most DOM elements a margin and/or padding that is not zero, including `body`.

I would recommend explictly setting `margin: 0; padding: 0;` on the `div` style. And then navigate further down to the `div` container and get *its* dimensions instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if you won to remove the write pixel around you do it with a simple filter that founds them after you create your image, then you found the final start and size of your image, and cut it.

You can do that using the `GetPixel(x, y)`

You can scan for example your image from top to bottom, and then from bottom to top, and the same right to left and left to right, to find the new size of the image that not contains white pixel.

For example, something like that:

```
for (int AxonX = 0; AxonX < wb.Width; AxonX++)
{
    for (int AxonY = 0; AxonY < wb.Height; AxonY++)
    {
        Color ThisPixelColor = wb.GetPixel(AxonX, AxonY);

        // Check if white or not and do the rest            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found how to solve my own problem.
Let me share the way how I solve so that other who will face the same problem can avoid the same difficulties.

First of all let me thank to @devstuff, and @Aristos.

My solution is below ...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        string _GenerateString = @"Number One 1<sup>st</sup> , the very first image creation.";
        StringBuilder sb_GenerateHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();
        sb_GenerateHTMLContent.Append(" <div style=\" white-space: nowrap \"> ");
        sb_GenerateHTMLContent.Append( _GenerateString );
        sb_GenerateHTMLContent.Append(" </div>");

        var bmp = MakeScreenshot(sb_GenerateHTMLContent.ToString());
        bmp.Save(@"C:\test_web.jpg");
    }

    public Bitmap MakeScreenshot(string html)
    {
        // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try
        {
            wb.Navigate("about:blank");
            if (wb.Document != null)
            {
                wb.Document.Write(html);
            }

            wb.DocumentText = html;
            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            wb.Width = 0;

            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            }

            StringBuilder sb_style_body = new StringBuilder();
            sb_style_body.Append(" margin-top:0; ");
            sb_style_body.Append(" margin-right:0; ");
            sb_style_body.Append(" margin-left:0; ");
            sb_style_body.Append(" margin-bottom:0; ");                
            sb_style_body.Append(" padding-top:0; ");
            sb_style_body.Append(" padding-bottom:0; ");
            sb_style_body.Append(" padding-right:0; ");
            sb_style_body.Append(" padding-left:0; ");
            sb_style_body.Append(" font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; ");
            sb_style_body.Append(" font-size:medium; ");

            wb.Document.Body.Style = sb_style_body.ToString();

            wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
            wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;

            bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
            wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            wb.Dispose();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```